# dynamically genereted svg path rendering issue on firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, snap.svg

I have created SVG path dynamically using javascript, but the paths are rendered properly in all browser even in IE except firefox(mine is 50.0).

My path attribute is looking like this
`d="M 134,145 l1,0 l8,0 ..."`.

I have also tried with space between points but no luck. Please help me on that.

Comment: We can't debug what we can't see. Please post an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/).

Comment: Your relative coordinate values are quite small. That said, the path seems to work for me (hand-crafted into an SVG) - did you set a stroke colour? What does `rendered properly in all [browsers] except firefox` look like a) using firefox 50.0(.1 here) b) say, Opera (30.0 here)? Post a snippet of the resulting page source code when you can't disclose the source code.